# Dot net core 5 publish on RHEL 8

Tags: .net-core

I am trying to publish a dot net core 5 web api on Red hat linux in AWS and access it over the internet using public ip address. I would like to test this application without using any proxy for now, i.e. directly using the built in Kestrel server in linux server

Steps I have taken

1. I have configured AWS EC2 instance with RHEL 8 and installed Dot net core 5 on the server.
2. In Visual Studio 2019 (Windows 10 env), created a sample web api i.e. weather application that comes by default. Ran it locally and confirm that it works
3. Published the application in a local folder in Visual Studio, using configuration=release option
4. Using winscp , copied the local folder contents to /var/www/html folder on the server
5. From the ec2 instance, ran the command dotnet webapp2.dll and get following output

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-93-219 html]$ dotnet webapp2.dll
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Now listening on: http://localhost:5000
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Hosting environment: Production
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Content root path: /var/www/html
```

6. From the browser, used public ip_address & port 5000 to access the web app. But it does not respond

http://54.205.158.241:5000/

Comment: additional info :  I ran the following command from the sever                                            dotnet webapp2.dll --urls "http://localhost:5000"

Comment: Also, realized only ports 22 and 80 are opened in the security group for the ec2 instance. Not sure how port 5000 will be opened

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's two problems here.

1. .NET is listening on `localhost` only. That means you can not connect to it from outside the machine (or EC2 instance, in this case). You need to have it listen on `0.0.0.0`
2. It's only listening on port 5000, while, as you say, you want to use port 80 to connect to it.

You can fix both these things at once by setting the `ASPNETCORE_URLS` environment variable:

For example, you can do:

```
export ASPNETCORE_URLS="*:80"
```

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel/endpoints?view=aspnetcore-6.0 for more details.